# Adding user and associated data CakePhp 3.x and receive validation errors for associated data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have scoured the internet and tried figuring this out with the docs, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I have users that can have a membership and many orders. The membership and orders are also associated with a membership level. I am unsure if these associations are correct, but I think they are.

Here are my associations:

Users:

```
    $this->hasOne('Memberships', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('MembershipOrders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Orders:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasOne('MembershipLevels', [
        'foreignKey' => 'membership_level_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Memberships:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasOne('MembershipLevels', [
        'foreignKey' => 'membership_level_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

MembershipLevels:

```
    $this->belongsToMany('MembershipOrders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'membership_level_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('Memberships', [
        'foreignKey' => 'membership_level_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

In my users controller I am trying to have a function that will add the user, a membership record, and an order for that user.

I am trying to make sure that validation errors are shown if any for the associated data in my form.

In the controller function I have:

```
public function checkout($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data(), [
        'associated' => [
            'MembershipOrders' => ['associated' => ['MembershipLevels']]
        ]
    ]);
    $membershipLevel = $this->Users->Memberships->MembershipLevels->get($id);
    if ( $this->request->is('post') ) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity( $user, $this->request->data(), [
            'associated' => [
                'MembershipOrders' => ['associated' => ['MembershipLevels']]
            ]
        ]);
        if ( $this->Users->save($user, ['associated' => ['MembershipOrders' => ['associated' => ['MembershipLevels']]]]) ) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('User has been added.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('User could not be added. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user', 'membershipLevel'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user', 'membershipLevel']);
}
```

A simple form for my view is:

```
    <?= $this->Form->create($user, ['id' => 'userForm']) ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?= __('Primary Member') ?></legend>
            <?= $this->Form->input('full_name', ['required' => false]) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('username', ['required' => false]) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('email', ['required' => false]) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password', ['required' => false]) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password_confirmation', ['type' => 'password', 'required' => false]) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('specialty', ['required' => false]) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('membership_orders.0.billing_name', ['label' => 'Name', 'data-stripe' => 'name', 'required' => false] ) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('membership_orders.0.billing_street_1', ['label' => 'Address 1', 'required' => false] ) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('membership_orders.0.billing_street_2', ['label' => 'Address 2', 'required' => false] ) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('membership_orders.0.billing_city', ['label' => 'City', 'data-stripe' => 'address_city', 'required' => false] ) ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Join'), ['id' => 'submitBtn', 'class' => 'btn']) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I have tried MembershipOrders, membershipOrders, the current membership_orders, and all with and without the .0 in the form and cannot get any validation errors for the order information. The billing info is to be added to the orders table and the exact table name is "membership_orders".

Shouldn't cake be sending associated validation errors to my form as well?

Comment: validation errors are contained inside $user->errors(); debug it , debug($user->errors());

Comment: Also, the keys is their current form are the correct ones. And note that `newEntity()` shouldn't be fed with anything in your example.